# ansi-term like interface for cider?

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

Is there a mode for Cider that will allow me to treat it like a REPL in ansi-term? That is, is there a way (like C-c C-j, C-c C-k in ansi-term) that lets me switch into treating it like a normal Emacs file vs. locked in place/using normal shell functionality (e.g. C-p for previous command)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Cider's maintainer. No, nothing like this exists. The REPL is implemented in a custom manner, without leveraging any standard Emacs machinery. We plan to reimplement it in terms of `comint-mode`, which would make a least some of the things you mentioned possible, but don't expect anything quite like `ansi-term`.